# Switching between two dataview webparts (No post back)

Tags: jquery, data-view-web-part

I have 2 DVWPs and would like to use a tab or link to switch between them without postbacks. I was thinking of using jQuery. One DVWP would have around 100 rows the other 400 rows.
Any suggestions would be great. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ready made solution if you don't want to program it yourself: http://jquerytabswebpart.codeplex.com/

If you want to implement it yourself, it is also very straightforward. Have two web part zones in the page, one DWP in each. In Page layout, add DIV's around each web part zone. Then add default CSS style that makes the second DIV initially hidden. Then add two buttons on top that toggle the visibility of the DIVs.

Of course, if you don't want the second DWP load before you click the tab, you need more sophisticated implementation, but with 100 and 400 items, this quick solution is probably quite OK.

Comment: Thanks Jussi for the link to codeplex.I was basically looking for something i could just use before that already existed.Thanks alot